# Trying to get the current user in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to get the current user in active admin for a model called `Type`.

Here are the contents of my file at `project/app/admin/type.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Type do    
  puts 'starting'
  puts proc {current_admin_user.id}
  puts 'finished'
  permit_params :name
end
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
starting
#<Proc:0x007f87e54f3c78@
finished
```

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you want to display your `current_admin_user.id` ? On the index page ?

Comment: I am actually wanting to do some logic with it, but for now I am just trying to find it so in this example I am just logging it to the web brick console.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting to see.  That code will only run when the environment is loaded (at server startup).

Comment: Also, if "Type" is the actual name of your model, I would avoid using that name.  It is a special designation in single table inheritance in rails and if this model is ever in say a has_many relationship this could cause problems when the has_many side tries to reference its "type".

Answer (score 2):

It actually works within the form, index or view blocks.

For example in your form block you can do this:

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        if current_admin_user.id == 1
            f.input :title
        else
           # do something else ...
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I need to access the current_admin_user method in my resource rather than in the controller so I can do some logic with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to access the userid so I created a migration with a role and then used current_admin_user.role? which worked fine and is really how I should have done it from the start :) rather than trying to find the id of the user.